A WordPress admin plugin menu link keeps erroring out
I have added a user and a new user role (SiteDeveloper) to a WordPress account for a developer to work on a project that has a customized Divi theme.
They can see the Divi plugin link at the bottom of the left admin menu but get an error message when trying to access it.
The message is:
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
and is displayed at this address:
[mywebsite.com]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=et_divi_options
I've given this role almost everything that an Administrator has.
When I log in as the administrator, the link works perfectly, but not when the developer logs in.
Need some guidance on how to resolve this.
Thanks!

Check Divi Plugin Settings -> divi role editor and grant permission to your roles. 
